# iOS 7 app size shrunk from 4'' to 3.5''

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

Using Xcode 5.0 the iOS 7 app I made is suddenly shown in 3.5'' size instead of 4'' both in iOS simulator and on an 4'' iPhone. I have no idea why this happened, I did some nonrelevant coding, nothing in the IB, and before it worked fine. See the black bars in the image. What could have caused this?

[image: Black bars]

Comment: Did your Default-568h@2x.png file go missing?

Comment: Thank you. As it turned out I removed the default *.xcassets file, when trying to remove a single element from it. Bad idea..